# How to make sure that JMS queue keep messages in a persistent storage rather than heap?

Tags: java, jms, persistence

My message size could reach 2MB, and I am expecting minimum 1000 messages to be available at a point.

Comment: What is your jms broker?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you persist the queue messages as you receive it?

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                messageDao.save(message); // <----- See you can persist then and there
            }
             catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }       

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is it possible to make sure that JMS keep the messages in database or hard-disk, rather than in memory heap?

Comment: I hope someone else can understand your question. Why is it in heap? It replaces the heap with every new message you receive. All the previous ones are lost if you didn't do anything with it.

Comment: @SerotoninChase Message should be in the JMS queue till it is not processed. Also, I am anticipating 1000s of messages with each message of around 2MB. This is why, it is important for me to make sure that messages go to persistent storage rather than in a heap. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Just to add on to the requirement, these 1000s of messages I am anticipating in the window of 15 minutes, and it will take around 5-7 minutes to process each message. Hence, I need it to go to hard disk straight than in heap.